# Gradient trick changed in iPhone 3.0 SDK?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, uicolor

I'm using a trick to get gradient on my table cells.

After I upgraded to the iPhone 3.0 SDK i noticed that the gradient highlighting, when I select a cell, no longer works.

iPhone 2.2.1
[image]

iPhone 3.0
[image]

Here's the gradient code:

```
    - (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Apply gradient fill
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 0.75 };
    CGFloat components[8] = {0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 1.0, // Start color
                             0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 1.0}; // End color 

    if (self.selected) {
        components[0] -= 0.10;
        components[1] -= 0.10;
        components[2] -= 0.10;
        components[4] -= 0.10;
        components[5] -= 0.10;
        components[6] -= 0.10;
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, 2);
    CGPoint start = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    CGPoint end = CGPointMake(0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, myGradient, start, end, 0);

    [textColor set];
    CGSize mainTextSize = [self.mainText sizeWithFont:(markedRead ? mainTextReadFont : mainTextFont) constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(288, 200) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [self.mainText drawInRect:CGRectMake(6, 4, mainTextSize.width, mainTextSize.height) withFont:(markedRead ? mainTextReadFont : mainTextFont)];

    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] set];
    [self.subText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(6, mainTextSize.height + 2) forWidth:288 withFont:subTextFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
}
```

If it isn't obvious, the code in `if (self.selected) {` decides the hightlight color.


**Anyone know what might cause this, possible a solution?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually solved this myself.

`if (self.selected) {`

has changed to
 `if (self.highlighted) {`

in iPhone 3.0

Comment: Actually, you can be `highlighted` without being `selected` (and possibly the other way around too). Usually I check for either with an or in my condition.